# Java error message => is undefined for the type -when creating an object from different package

Tags: java, eclipse

I have the following code where I am calling a class from another package and I get:

> undefined for the type

Package A:

```
import Excel.WriteExcel;
   public void setupAfterSuite() {

    WriteExcel x = new WriteExcel();

    **x.WriteResults(testresultdata, sheet, workbook);**
```

Getting the following error:

> The method WriteResults(Map, HSSFSheet, HSSFWorkbook)
>   is undefined for the type WriteExcel

Package B:

```
public void WriteResults(Map<String, Object[]> testresultdata1, HSSFSheet readsheet1, HSSFWorkbook workbook1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Set<String> keyset = testresultdata1.keySet();
        int rownum = 0;
        for (String key : keyset) {
            Row row = readsheet1.createRow(rownum++);

            Object [] objArr = testresultdata1.get(key);



            int cellnum = 0;
            for (Object obj : objArr) {
                Cell cell = row.createCell(cellnum++);
                if(obj instanceof Date) 
                    cell.setCellValue((Date)obj);
                else if(obj instanceof Boolean)
                    cell.setCellValue((Boolean)obj);
                else if(obj instanceof String)
                    cell.setCellValue((String)obj);
                else if(obj instanceof Double)
                    cell.setCellValue((Double)obj);
                readsheet1.autoSizeColumn(rownum);

                for(int i=rownum; i>0; i--){

                    readsheet1.autoSizeColumn(i);

               }
```

It's probably something minor.  Can anyone please advise.

Thanks

Comment: How did you declare testresultdata?

Comment: these are compile time errors or runtime ?

Comment: Hi I declared it as follows:  
Map<String, Object[]> testresultdata;
testresultdata = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object[]>();tresultdata = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object[]>();

Comment: Declared in Package A

Comment: Hi I declared it as follows:  
Map<String, Object[]> testresultdata;
testresultdata = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object[]>();

Answer (score 0):

You are not sharing some important information, so don't be surprised no-one helped you...

Let me try the same, what you are saying you did.

You didn't share first class name and package name, so I named it `ClassA` and is defined in `q34201803.a` package:

```
package q34201803.a;

import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;

import Excel.WriteExcel;

public class ClassA {

    public void setupAfterSuite() {

        WriteExcel x = new WriteExcel();

        HSSFSheet sheet = null;
        HSSFWorkbook workbook = null;
        Map<String, Object[]> testresultdata;
        testresultdata = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object[]>();
        x.WriteResults(testresultdata, sheet, workbook);
    }

}
```

Then I created second class based on import in your code:

```
package Excel;

import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;

public class WriteExcel {

    public void WriteResults(Map<String, Object[]> testresultdata1, HSSFSheet readsheet1, HSSFWorkbook workbook1) {
        // not important...
    }

}
```

and it works fine for me.

Please share full source code of your classes I think, there might be problem in imports.

Also you should learn Java [naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) if you want to code in Java.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sorry I am new to Coding
**Here is all of the code:**

package Excel;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;

public class WriteExcel {



    public void WriteResults(Map<String, Object[]> testresultdata1, HSSFSheet readsheet1, HSSFWorkbook workbook1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Set<String> keyset = testresultdata1.keySet();
        int rownum = 0;
        for (String key : keyset) {
            Row row = readsheet1.createRow(rownum++);

            Object [] objArr = testresultdata1.get(key);


            int cellnum = 0;
            for (Object obj : objArr) {
                Cell cell = row.createCell(cellnum++);
                if(obj instanceof Date) 
                    cell.setCellValue((Date)obj);
                else if(obj instanceof Boolean)
                    cell.setCellValue((Boolean)obj);
                else if(obj instanceof String)
                    cell.setCellValue((String)obj);
                else if(obj instanceof Double)
                    cell.setCellValue((Double)obj);
                readsheet1.autoSizeColumn(rownum);

                for(int i=rownum; i>0; i--){

                    readsheet1.autoSizeColumn(i);

               }



                try {
                    File dir = new File("Results");
                    dir.mkdir();
                    FileOutputStream out =new FileOutputStream(new File("Results/TestResult.xls"));
                    workbook1.write(out);
                    out.close();
                    System.out.println("Excel written successfully..");

                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
    }
}
}


**This is the second Class:**


package test;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.testng.ITestContext;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import Excel.WriteExcel;
import jxl.Workbook;
import jxl.read.biff.BiffException;


public class UserSettingTest {

      //define an Excel Work Book
      HSSFWorkbook workbook;
      //define an Excel Work sheet
      HSSFSheet sheet;
      //define a test result data object
      Map<String, Object[]> testresultdata;
      //define an Excel Work Book
      HSSFWorkbook workbookRead;
      //define an Excel Work sheet
      HSSFSheet Readsheet;



    @BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
      public void setupBeforeSuite(ITestContext context) {

         //create a new work book
          workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
          //create a new work sheet
           //sheet = workbook.createSheet("Test Result");
          testresultdata = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object[]>();
          //add test result excel file column header
          //write the header in the first row
          testresultdata.put("1", new Object[] {"Test Step Id", "Action", "Expected Result","Actual Result"});



        }



    @DataProvider(name = "DP1")
    public Object[][] createData1() throws BiffException, IOException
    {
        Object[][] retObjArr=getTableArray("data1.xls", "DataPool", "imdbTestData1" );
        return (retObjArr);

    }


      @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private Object[][] getTableArray(String xlFilePath, String SheetName, String tableName) throws BiffException, IOException {
          String[][] tabArray=null;

          Workbook workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File(xlFilePath));
          jxl.Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(SheetName); 
          int startRow,startCol, endRow, endCol,ci,cj;
          jxl.Cell tableStart=sheet.findCell(tableName);
          startRow=tableStart.getRow();
          startCol=tableStart.getColumn();

          jxl.Cell tableEnd= sheet.findCell(tableName, startCol+1,startRow+1, 100, 64000,  false);                

          endRow=tableEnd.getRow();
          endCol=tableEnd.getColumn();
          System.out.println("startRow="+startRow+", endRow="+endRow+", " +
                  "startCol="+startCol+", endCol="+endCol);
          tabArray=new String[endRow-startRow-1][endCol-startCol-1];
          ci=0;

          for (int i=startRow+1;i<endRow;i++,ci++){
              cj=0;
              for (int j=startCol+1;j<endCol;j++,cj++){
                  tabArray[ci][cj]=sheet.getCell(j,i).getContents();
              }
          }


      return(tabArray);


    }


      int RowNo =3;
      int testCase=1;

      @Test
    public void testDataProviderExample(String movieTitle, 
                String directorName, String moviePlot, String actorName) throws Exception {    
          //start
          String SRowNo = "" + RowNo;
          String StestCase =   "TC"+ testCase ;

          System.out.println("DirectorName is: "+directorName);
          System.out.println("DirectorName is: "+moviePlot);
          System.out.println("DirectorName is: "+actorName);

        testresultdata.put(SRowNo, new Object[] {StestCase,directorName, "Logged Out","Fail"});


          RowNo++;
          testCase++;
        }

    @AfterClass
      public void setupAfterSuite() {

        WriteExcel x = new WriteExcel();

        x.WriteResults(testresultdata, Readsheet, workbook);



        try {
            File dir = new File("Results");
            dir.mkdir();
            FileOutputStream out =new FileOutputStream(new File("Results/TestResult.xls"));
            workbook.write(out);
            out.close();
            System.out.println("Excel written successfully..");

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

      }


    }

**When i run i get the following**

[TestNG] Running:
  C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\testng-eclipse-859939429\testng-customsuite.xml

FAILED CONFIGURATION: @AfterClass setupAfterSuite
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Excel.WriteExcel.WriteResults(WriteExcel.java:26)
    at test.UserSettingTest.setupAfterSuite(UserSettingTest.java:127)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:85)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:510)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:211)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:138)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeAfterClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:220)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:773)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:623)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:357)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:352)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:310)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:259)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1185)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1110)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1018)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)



Line 26 referring to:     ===>    Row row = readsheet1.createRow(rownum++);
```

Comment: it's not about the coding, more about SO, you will learn ;-) Please edit your question, do not use the answer for that ;-)

Comment: but there is completely different exception in the log compared to your original question, NPE can be only because readsheet1 is null... Which in this context says, that `Readsheet` is null. Are you setting it somewhere or I missed something? @AfterClass runs after all tests, not after each one, is that ok for you ?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't initialize the `Readsheet` object. This way, you're passing a null argument to `WriteResults` method.

```
x.WriteResults(testresultdata, Readsheet, workbook);
```

That causes `NullPointerException` at this line.

```
Row row = readsheet1.createRow(rownum++);
```

`readsheet1` is null.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the code and it is now working. Thanks Betlista and hbelmiro